# Plotting negative and positive in the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data table:

```
 data <- structure(list(Dep = c("D1", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D9", 
    "D12"), IND1 = c(0.75093, -0.11708, -0.58419, NA, -2.40179, 0.26907, 
    -2.30089, NA)), .Names = c("Dep", "IND1"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000047b0788>)
```

I would like to create a plot for IND1. In x axis I would like to have the number values and y axis the name of Dep column. Is it possible to create a bar which will show which have positive (going to right) and negative (going to left side) bars?

I tried something like this:

```
barplot(data, 
    horiz=TRUE, 
    xlim=c(-500,500), 
    xlab="IND1", 
    axisnames=FALSE)
```

How can I change xlim to my case? Also how can I add blue color for positive and read color for negative bars and the name of every bar according to Dep column row value in y axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling your data `dd`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd, aes(x = Dep, y = IND1, fill = (IND1 > 0))) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_fill_manual(value = c("purple", "blue")) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Is there any rule could added for bar greater than 0 be blue and less than 0 purple?

Comment: add `fill = (IND1>0)` within `aes()` and `scale_colour_manual(value=c("purple","blue"))` (or something like that)

Comment: @BenBolker is this right `ggplot(dd, aes(x = Dep, y = IND1, fill = (IND1>0))) + geom_col() + scale_colour_manual(value=c("purple","blue")) + coord_flip()` ?

Comment: seems right, but I haven't tested it.  Does it give you the result you want?

Comment: Needs to be `scale_fill_manual`, and the arg is `values =` not `value =` (no partial matching here). See updates.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick.  I named your data `df` for this working example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(sign = ifelse(IND1 > 0, "Pos", "Neg"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Dep, y = IND1, fill = factor(sign))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()
```

Edit:  Added your color requests.  Would you mind clarifying what you mean  by the "name of every bar according to Dep column row value in y axis"?